# Converting .htaccess to nginx (mod_rewrite)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I've got the following .htaccess file for my apache:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks    
# Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^$          index.php       [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}         !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}         !-d
  RewriteRule (.*)        index.php?page=$1  [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Suddenly I had to change my webserver to nginx and I don't know why, but the mod rewrite is not working.

I used an online 'converter' to convert it, so I've got the following:

```
location / {
  rewrite ^/$ /         index.php       break;
  if ($request_filename ~         !-f){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /       index.php?page=$1   break;
  }
}
```

Could you help me what's wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Marcell

Comment: What idiot closed this? Updating mod rewrite rules when moving from Apache not nginx is necessary for the majority of sites.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

http://web.archive.org/web/20180812021847/https://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2011/02/nginx-primer-2-from-apache-to-nginx/

Everything is inside. No more .htaccess, no more complex rules use try_files.

**EDIT**: And if it is not obvious, do not trust online converters.

Answer (score 0):

$ sudo vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
  location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

to

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```