# Nginx Mod_Rewrite all pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

i want to move to nginx since it's better than apache. but i'm confusing.

if it's not found the pages requested, nginx need to mod_rewrite.
my `.htaccess` :

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
</Files>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./go.php?code=$1
```

Then what is nginx mod rewrite for it?

Using apache, I just need to add `.htaccess` on folder.
but how to add it on nginx?

Comment: "I decided to change my run-of-the-mill locks on my house with electronic locks. Now my run-of-the-mill keys don't work anymore on my electronic locks. How did that happen?!"

Comment: why you add negative vote? and why you're spamming?

Comment: If you hover over the downvote button you might be able to see why someone gave a downvote: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.". My comment was meant to get you thinking. The answer is meant to answer the question. It overlaps with the comment, because it is meant to be complete for a future visitor that has the same problem. They are not to be expected to read the comments under the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927184/converting-htaccess-to-nginx-mod-rewrite/14967560#14967560

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you expect an Apache config file to work with an entirely other http deamon. It's like expecting that you can use your old car keys with your new car. It is simply not going to work. If you want to transfer your Apache rewrite rules to nginx, you'll need to translate them into the syntax of nginx in the configuration file that nignx uses.

You can find the documentation of nginx' rewrite module [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html).