# HTACCESS 2 NGINX Rule,any can help me?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

i have one site need to move from apache2 to nginx,everything is ok ,except the htaccess. i have google some online tools (http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/ & http://winginx.com/en/htaccess ... ),but they all didn't work, even one rule :( !

anyone can help me ,thank you!!!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

#First rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use the correct one (here www.)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Now, rewrite to HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc         off
    php_flag magic_quotes_runtime     off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc         off
    php_flag magic_quotes_runtime     off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: ouch, please do not do that in this way, check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927184/converting-htaccess-to-nginx-mod-rewrite/14967560#14967560 . Again this is a try_files case, not a rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Found an interesting website that does the job: convert htaccess to nginx configurations:

http://winginx.com/en/htaccess

According to the automatic conversion, it's translated to:

```
# nginx configuration
location ~ /index.php$ {
}
location / {
    if ($http_host !~ "^www\."){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ https://www.$http_host$request_uri redirect;
    }
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$http_host$request_uri redirect;
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php break;
    }
}
```

Seems like the php modules configuration is not converted (way to customized for a generic tool). Please let me know whether this is working fine.