# Yii redirects to homepage with index.php

Tags: yii

I have a Yii project on Ubuntu Nginx server that is migrated from Apache and now behaving strange. URLs with `index.php (http://sitename/index.php/site/about)` are working ok but `http://sitename/site/about` displays homepage. 
I've tried demo blog that comes with Yii and both urls(with and without index.php part) on same server works as expected. So NGINS server block is set up correctly and u part on UrlManager section of Yi config is the same on both project and a blog demo.

```
'urlManager' => array (
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'caseSensitive' => false,
```

Where should I look for a problem source?

Comment: Do you convert rewrite rules from apache to nginx? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927184/converting-htaccess-to-nginx-mod-rewrite

Comment: @SiZE yes i've tried `location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }`
And default demo blog is working ok but my app not.
In Apache i had `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Maybe this wiki will help http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/15/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Yii app config:

```
 'components' => array (
                            'request' => array (
                                    'baseUrl' => 'http://sitename',
                            ),...
```

Removing the request block solved the problem.
However on Apache was a workaround rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^(.​​*​)\?​*​​$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]*​`

Answer (score 0):

Kindly follow below steps to remove index.php from URL in Yii.

Step-1: Open file protected/config/main.php and set following settings and save.

```
'urlManager' => array(
     'showScriptName' => false,
```

Step-2 .htaccess Changes:

```
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

If .htaccess is not working then enable it with following steps.

First enable rewrite using this command:

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then restart apache2:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then go into the sites-available folder:

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
```

Edit the file named default and change AllowOverride none to AllowOverride All. There are two lines where this change has to be made.
This will make .htaccess work in your server.

Open and edit from this file vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
 AllowOverride all
 Options None
 Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Finally restart apache2 service to apply all changes

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```