# Is it possible to create a dynamic page accesible from "/example" path without creating folders?

Tags: php, html, url, path

I know its posible to get different results by using GET and a path like this:

```
www.example.com/user?name=a
```

I have been looking for some sites (based on the same theme as me) where they use paths like:

```
/username/Jonh
```

Since there will be 100+ 'usernames' I think its ridiculous to create manually 100 folders for this.
I'm just wondering if its posible to create a dynamic page accesible by paths like:

```
www.example.com/user/a
www.example.com/user/b
```

Comment: Read about htaccess https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules

Comment: The answer is _YES_, you can use urls like that without a matching directory structure. How is another question, one that has been asked here many, many times... [here's a related question that shows you how this is done in both apache and nginx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927184/converting-htaccess-to-nginx-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, there is something called `mod_rewrite`, if you are using Apache. You can read about it here: [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

For other webservers, there are similar modules.